# How to get public access to edit a layer in geoserver

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs-t, boundless-suite, authentication

I want to develop a GIS system with OpenLayers and GeoServer which is installed with OpenGeo Suite 4.1 and I need to edit a layer with no GeoServer authentication. This means that guest members should have permission to edit a layer.

How can I do this?

Comment: By default no authentication is needed to edit using WFS-T. Are you having any problems with doing so? what have you tried? Where are you current stuck? You'll tend to get better quality answers if you post your research first.

Comment: You're right, But in new version of geoserver transaction set to admin Role, and now I delete it and solve my problem. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use GeoServer in OpenGeo Suite 4.1. In this package, the "Service access rules list" page has a rule that only "ADMIN" roles have permission for WFS-Transaction.

```
wfs.Transation --> ADMIN
```

You must delete this rule.